# Yii 1. Как доставать не все атрибуты модели по умолчанию

Tags: yii, criteria

Например мне нужны данные модели User, все поля кроме token и password.
Если я буду поднимать модель то я получу все атрибуты, в том числе и пароль. Эти данные мне нужны редко, только при авторизации и аутентификация.
А в основном я заношу атрибуты в json и обрабатываю, вывожу то что мне нужно, но это не безопасно так как можно получить пароль и токен.
Такая же проблема состоит и с релейшенами, например

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
        );
    }
```

Если буду доставать с другой модели user, то получу все поля. 
Как правильно и где прописать в одном месте, чтобы по умолчанию получал все кроме token и password?

Есть идея использовать `afterFind()`

```
public function afterFind() {
        $this->_password=$this->password;
        $this->password=null;
        $this->_token=$this->token;
        $this->token;

        parent::afterFind();
    }
```

Comment: А вы пользовались сценариями ? http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/ 
array('field1, field2, field3, 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),

Или можно так  User::model()->findByPk(15)->findColumn('field1', 'field2')

Comment: Я сценарии использовал при валидации формы в разных режимах, но как они мне тут помогут? User::model()->findByPk(15)->findColumn('field1', 'field2') мне кажется не подойдет, так как у меня сотни запросов find где не нужно получать поле password, и я не буду в каждом прописывать, что мне доставать, мне нужно исключить несколько полей во всех запросах сразу, в том числе и через relation.

Comment: Если в rules прописать array('id'', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'), то $model=User::model()->findByPk(15);
$model->setScenario('search');
$model - все равно возвращает все поля

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 't.first_name, t.email'; // выбрать поля которые нужно вывести
$criteria->condition = 't.status = 1';

$data = Users::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

$data выведет массив

Или я неправильно понял, тоесть нужно по умолчанию постоянно?

А что если CActiveRecord::defaultScope()

```
class Service extends CActiveRecord
{
    ...
    public function defaultScope(){
        return array(
            'order'=>'pos ASC'
        );
    }
    ...
}
```

Будет правда додан ко всем методам поиска модели

Comment: попробую defaultScope